# Java - Converting 20 bytes value to base-10 number

Tags: java, arrays

I have one query regarding the bytes to int/long conversion in Java.

There are:

- 4-bytes for Integer
- 8-bytes for Long.

How I can store values that wil take more than 8 bytes
and how Java will represents this (example: 8 + bytes value in memory)?

Comment: maybe `BigInteger`? Format is 2's complement.

Comment: You mean something like `BigInteger`? (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-byte:A-)

Comment: Yes I agree but suppose I pass my 20 bytes data to BigInterger how do I validate the number what it returns if its correct or not?
Apart form BigInterger is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Suppose my 
20 byes data --> 8df0c57980d7fa44e3a7286cfd9a4589c5eb1eb0 (BCD representation)
Converted base 10 value --> 810337079999566180844224202226604022424802268880 (Result what I except)
What BigInteger gives me is --> (-651164557331336638185274147278897710880573940048)

And I don't understand how this base-10 number is derived.

Comment: @yash- BigInteger doesn't give you a direct conversion from BCD to BigInteger! You probably might have implemented something incorrect! Please edit the question with what you tried as code and what you received as an output!

Comment: Clearified the question. Formated text.

Comment: @Shekhar Yes I have just put BCD for representation purpose.
I am not passing this BCD string to BigInteger but its actual bytes.
My Question is what are the differet ways I can represents the more than 8 bytes value to base-10 value?

Comment: @Beri thanks for formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is designed for this. Internally, it represents numbers with a (variable-length) vector that can be seen as a polynomial. It allows arbitrary-sized integers to be manipulated efficiently, as long as there is enough free memory to do so. Other languages have similar constructs or libraries; for instance, the [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library follows a similar approach.

Note that, although `BigInteger`s can be built from `byte[]` two's complement, and can be converted to those `byte[]`s again, internally they are using a more-efficient `int[]` representation. When in doubt, [read the source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/BigInteger-source.html).

Sample code follows:

```
import java.math.*;
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            // build from base-16 string representation
            BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s, 16); 
            System.out.println("The decimal representation of \n\t"
                + s + " is \n\t" + bi);
            // (bi.toString() generates base-10 strings)
        }
    }
}
```

Now compile & run:

```
javac T.java && java T 8df0c57980d7fa44e3a7286cfd9a4589c5eb1eb0
```

Output as expected:

```
The decimal representation of
    8df0c57980d7fa44e3a7286cfd9a4589c5eb1eb0 is 
    810337079999566280018410685437385308775358602928
```